# How to place content below the inner box shadow?

Tags: html, css

Do you have any suggestions?

```css
.container {
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px gray inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="item">Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p class="item">Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

EDIT: I should have been more specific with my question, sorry. I want to see the shadow above the text. I have a container and when I scroll down, I want the content to be seen as going below the shadow.

[image]

As you can see, there is an inner shadow but it is not positioned at the top.

Comment: use a pseudo-element to create the shadow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
:root {
  --main-inline-size: 80%;
  --main-max-inline-size: 1200px;
  --main-min-inline-size: 20rem;
  --spacing: 0.5rem;
}

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  block-size: 100vh;
  font-family: system-ui;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: var(--spacing);
}

menu,
ol,
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

main {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  inline-size: clamp(var(--main-min-inline-size), var(--main-inline-size), var(--main-max-inline-size));
  margin-inline: auto;
  min-block-size: 100%;
  padding: var(--spacing);
}

/* the code following this comment is relevant, the prior code is for
   simple resets and base-styling: */

.container {
  /* using CSS custom properties to assign both
     colour and size for the shadow; the shadow
     size is deliberately ridiculously large for
     the purposes of this demonstration: */
  --shadowSize: 5rem;
  --shadowColor: lime;
  block-size: 50vmin;
  /* setting the padding of the element to a fraction of the
     shadow's size, in order to ensure the shadow extends
     "over" the content: */
  padding: calc(var(--shadowSize)/4);
  /* for positioning the pseudo-element: */
  position: relative;
}

.container::after {
  /* defining the box-shadow, using the custom properties: */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 var(--shadowSize) var(--shadowColor);
  content: '';
  /* ensuring the element is positioned up to the edges of
     its parent: */
  inset: 0;
  /* to allow interaction with the contents "below"/"beneath"
     the shadow, and pseudo-element: */
  pointer-events: none;
  /* for sizing and positioning: */
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="item">Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p class="item">Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gd4jbets/).

Comment: I got the idea. Thank you for your answer and effort. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, but is this what you looking for? The "Lorem Ipsum" is now written below the inner box shadow.

`HTML`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <p class="item">Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p class="item">Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

`CSS`

```
      
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 25px; 
  background-color: transparent;
}

.container .content {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px gray inset;
 padding: 20px; 
}

.item {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

[image: Text inside]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is not what I'm looking for, I should have been more specific, sorry. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

use a "padding" property and set the value, for example I want to set 20 px. And then the text will be below your inner shadow. I hope this help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).